# Public API or URL format for Google+ profile photo given gmail address?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, identity, avatar

I know I can get it with a Google+ user ID, but I don't have that, I just have the users'  email address. I don't want to make them login with their Google account.

Is it possible to get the photo? I'm thinking not, but I just wanted to make sure. Here's the most info on it I could find:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the feature request says, there is no way to look up a Google+ profile via email address. Since the only way to get a profile's avatar is by looking up their profile, there is no way to get a profile's avatar via email.

[Gravatar](https://secure.gravatar.com/) might be a better fit for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get their name and profile photo with [avatarapi](http://www.avatarapi.com)